# How to restrict the directory search using URL rewrite

Tags: iis, web-config

I have used the following code in my web config under system.webServer, This is working as expected

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RequestBlockingRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(.*)" />
        <add input="Html5Viewer1.html" negate="true" pattern="(.*).html" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" statusReason="Resource NotFound" statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**Now, I want to issue "404 - Not Found" for the following directory search also**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule to block access to Images：

```
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^images/(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^$" />
      </conditions>
   <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" statusReason="File or directory not found." statusDescription="The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." />
</rule>
```

[image]